# Finding view that was currently inflated via setConteView(...)

Tags: android, android-layout

I just want to add to my `Linearlayout` simple `textView` programmaticly

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Any text");
        View parent = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)parent.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        l.addView(tv);
    }
```

However i get an error. 
I am sure i am missing something obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do????

Comment: add `textView` to my currently inflated layout programmaticly

Comment: And that layout is available in your `activity_main` ?

Comment: I want to _catch_ my `activity_main`

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What exactly you want?

Comment: @Anarantt you get an error!. post the same here.

Comment: I`ve just found mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Any text");
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutId);
        l.addView(tv);
    }
```

Linear layout contain into activity_main.xml file